# Circular import using flask and discord bot

Tags: python, discord

I have these two files:

main.py

```
import os
import discord
from keep_alive import keep_alive
client = discord.Client()

my_secret = os.environ['Token']

async def SendMeMessage():
  user = await client.fetch_user('my id')
  await user.create_dm()
  await user.dm_channel.send("Someone needs help")
  
keep_alive()
client.run(my_secret)
```

keep_alive.py

```
from flask import Flask
from threading import Thread
#from main import SendMeMessage

app = Flask('')
@app.route('/')
def home():
  #SendMeMessage()
  return "Hello. I am alive!"

def run():
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)

def keep_alive():
  t = Thread(target=run)
  t.start()
```

And I would like to import SendMemessage. So when someone send get request on flask server, I wanna receive message from my discord bot. I'm stuck on error "circular import", when I implement commented code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would move the discord bot code out of `main.py`, so it no longer depends on an import of `keep_alive`.

bot.py:

```
import os
import discord

client = discord.Client()

async def SendMeMessage():
  user = await client.fetch_user('my id')
  await user.create_dm()
  await user.dm_channel.send("Someone needs help")
```

keep_alive.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from threading import Thread
from bot import SendMeMessage

app = Flask('')
@app.route('/')
def home():
  SendMeMessage()
  return "Hello. I am alive!"

def run():
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)

def keep_alive():
  t = Thread(target=run)
  t.start()
```

main.py:

```py
import os

from keep_alive import keep_alive
from bot import client

my_secret = os.environ['Token']

keep_alive()
client.run(my_secret)
```

This way, `bot.py` has already been fully imported when `keep_alive.py` runs, so there is no longer a circular import.